# Capitalize the drop down (option) values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am retrieving values from DB and binding it in haml. I am trying to capitalize the values in drop down option.

models.rb

```
class EnumValue < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :enum_type, :name, :gdsn
  scope :countries, EnumValue.where(enum_type: "country").order(:name)
end
```

form.html.haml

```
.offset1.span2
        = f.association :country, :collection => EnumValue.countries,:include_blank => "Select Country",:label => "Country of Origin",:selected =>@records.country_id ? @records.country_id, :input_html => {:onchange =>"setGdsnName(this.value,'country')"}
```

I tried to call capitalize on `EnumValue.countries.capitalize` in haml, and I got the following error: `undefined method capitalize for # ActiveRecord::Relation:0x123d0718>`.

Can anyone tell me how to capitalize the values in drop down using active records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map` to `capitalize` each value in an array:

```
EnumValue.countries.map(&:capitalize)
```

Btw for your use case `titleize` might be the better option, because it can handle country names including multiple words:

```
"United States".capitalize
#=> "United states"
```

Whereas:

```
"United States".titleize
#=> "United States"
```

Furthermore you need to get the country names from the returned collection, since your `countries` does not return an array of country names but instances of `EnumValue`:

```
EnumValue.countries.map { |c| [c.name.titleize, c.id] }
```

Comment: I tried "EnumValue.countries.map(&:titleize)"  in form.html.haml. I am getting the following error "undefined method `titleize' for #<EnumValue:0x1116f86c>". Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Working now. Good answer with explanation!

Answer (score 1):

if you define a `titleized_contries` method in `EnumValue`:

```
def titleized_contries
  countries.map(&:titleize)
end
```

you can elegantly use `collection_select`

```
f.collection_select(:country, EnumValue.countries, :id, titleized_contries, include_blank: "Select Country", label: "Country of Origin")
```